# Which is the closest Python equivalent to Perl::Tidy?

Tags: python, emacs, code-formatting, perl-tidy

Coming from Perl I've been used to hitting <kbd>C-c t</kbd> to reformat my code according to pre-defined `Perl::Tidy` rules. Now, with Python I'm astonished to learn that there is nothing that even remotely resembles the power of `Perl::Tidy`. PythonTidy 1.20 looks almost appropriate, but barfed at first mis-aligned line ("unexpected indent").

In particular, I'm looking for the following:

- Put PEP-8 into use as far as possible (the following items are essentially derivations of this one)
- Convert indentation tabs to spaces
- Remove trailing spaces
- Break up code according to the predefined line-length as far as it goes (Eclipse-style string splitting and splitting method chains)
- Normalize whitespace around
- (bonus feature, optional) Re-format code including indentation.

Right now, I'm going throught someone else's code and correct everything `pep8` and `pyflakes` tell me, which is mostly "remove trailing space" and "insert additional blank line". While I know that re-indentation is not trivial in Python (even though it should be possible just by going through the code and remembering the indentation), other features seem easy enough that I can't believe nobody has implemented this before.

Any recommendations?

**Update**: I'm going to take a deeper look at PythonTidy, since it seems to go into the right direction. Maybe I can find out why it barfs at me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `reindent.py` script distributed with python in the `scripts` directory.

Comment: It available from PyPi and doesn't work properly -- a mis-indented file is not corrected. Apparently, only valid indentations are changed, e.g. from 2 spaces to 4.

Comment: An incorrectly indented file might be ambiguous, how would a script know what you really mean?

Comment: @Nick: first line of code shouldn't be ambiguous, especially when it's `from foo import baz`.

Answer (score 0):

[untabify.py](http://www.koders.com/python/fidD96A81172DCD7CEAE5697C0022400F212A46CB10.aspx?s=python#L1) (`Tools/scripts/untabify.py` from the root directory of a Python source distribution) should fix the tabs, which may be what's stopping Python Tidy from doing the rest of the work.

Comment: Yes, Emacs does that too with its `untabify` command. But that's just one problem, which is a non-issue after an initial conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a wrapper around pythontidy?  There's one for the [sublime editor here](https://bitbucket.org/theblacklion/sublime_python_tidy/).

Also, does pythontidy break up long lines properly for you? When I have a long line that ends in a tuple, it creates a new line for every entry in the tuple, instead of using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces as suggested by PEP-8.

Comment: An official wrapper by the author of PythonTidy exists [here](http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidyWrapper.python). I've had a couple of problems with PythonTidy initially and have mailed the author, who prompty released a [PythonTidy 1.21](http://lacusveris.com/PythonTidy/PythonTidy-1.21.python), which is not linked from PyPI. I'm still not fully satisfied, but I haven't had the time to note every problem and/or patch it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) for this purpose and found it handy.